# How to get Java to use the correct character set?

Tags: java, character-encoding, centos, cp1252

We've got our servers running on CentOS and our Java backend sometimes has to process a file that was originally generated on a Windows machine (by one of our clients) using CP-1252, however in 95%+ use cases, we are processing UTF-8 files.

My question: if we know that certain files will *always* be UTF-8, and other files will *always* be CP-1252, is it possible to specify in Java the character set to use for reading in each file? If so:

- Do we need to do anything at the systems-level for adding CP-1252 to CentOS? If so, what does this involve?
- What Java objects would we use to apply the correct encoding on a per file basis?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you read a file, you [specify the encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question: if we know that certain files will always be UTF-8, and other files will always be CP-1252, is it possible to specify in Java the character set to use for reading in each file?

Assuming you're in charge of the code reading the file, it should be fine. Create a `FileInputStream`, then wrap it in an `InputStreamReader` specifying the relevant character encoding.

> Do we need to do anything at the systems-level for adding CP-1252 to CentOS? If so, what does this involve?

That depends on what the JRE supports. I've never used CentOS, so I don't know whether it's likely to come with the relevant encoding as part of the JRE. You can use [`Charset.isSupported`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#isSupported%28java.lang.String%29) to check though, and [`Charset.availableCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#availableCharsets%28%29) to list what's available.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is specify what charset/encoding the original file was written in while using the `XXXReader(InputStream in, Charset cs)`. For e.g. look at [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)